# Vincular select>option com Onclick do botao. Jogo da Velha

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos, onclick

Eu gostaria de vincular o meu select box com a função que é chamada no on click.

tenho duas opções: Player v s Player e CPU vs Player ... a ideia é que quando alguém selecionar "Player vs Player" o On click da celula seja function jogada(p), e quando algém selecionar "Player vs CPU" o Onclick chame a função jogadaComp(p)

```js
function jogadaComp(p){
    numJogadas++;
    verificaVez(quemJoga);
    
    if((quemJoga === 0) && (jogoRolando === true)){
        switch(p){
                case 00 :
                if(jogo[0][0] === ''){
                    jogo[0][0] = 'X';
                    quemJoga = 1;
                }; break;
                
                case 01 :
                if(jogo[0][1] === ''){
                    jogo[0][1] = 'X';
                    quemJoga = 1;
                }; break;
                case 02 :
                if(jogo[0][2] === ''){
                    jogo[0][2] = 'X';
                    quemJoga = 1;
                }; break;
                case 10 :
                if(jogo[1][0] === ''){
                    jogo[1][0] = 'X';
                    quemJoga = 1;
                }; break;            
                case 11 :
                if(jogo[1][1] === ''){
                    jogo[1][1] = 'X';
                    quemJoga = 1;
                }; break;            
                case 12 :
                if(jogo[1][2] === ''){
                    jogo[1][2] = 'X';
                    quemJoga = 1;
                }; break;            
                case 20 :
                if(jogo[2][0] === ''){
                    jogo[2][0] = 'X';
                    quemJoga = 1;
                }; break;            
                case 21 :
                if(jogo[2][1] === ''){
                    jogo[2][1] = 'X';
                    quemJoga = 1;
                }; break;            
                case 22 :
                if(jogo[2][2] === ''){
                    jogo[2][2] = 'X';
                    quemJoga = 1;
                }; break;
        }
    }
       
    
    cpuJoga();
    atualizaTabuleiro();
    vitoria = verificaVitoria();
    
    if (vitoria != ''){
        if (quemJoga = 0){
           // alert(vitoria + " Venceu!");
           mensagemWinner(vitoria);
            jogoRolando=false;
        } else {
            mensagemWinner(vitoria);
               // alert(vitoria + " Venceu!");
                jogoRolando=false;
            
        }
    }
}


//// outra função :


function jogada(p){
    numJogadas++
    verificaVez(quemJoga);
    
    if((quemJoga === 0) && (jogoRolando === true)){
        switch(p){
                case 00 :
                if(jogo[0][0] === ''){
                    jogo[0][0] = 'X';
                    quemJoga = 1;
                }; break;
                
                case 01 :
                if(jogo[0][1] === ''){
                    jogo[0][1] = 'X';
                    quemJoga = 1;
                }; break;
                case 02 :
                if(jogo[0][2] === ''){
                    jogo[0][2] = 'X';
                    quemJoga = 1;
                }; break;
                case 10 :
                if(jogo[1][0] === ''){
                    jogo[1][0] = 'X';
                    quemJoga = 1;
                }; break;            
                case 11 :
                if(jogo[1][1] === ''){
                    jogo[1][1] = 'X';
                    quemJoga = 1;
                }; break;            
                case 12 :
                if(jogo[1][2] === ''){
                    jogo[1][2] = 'X';
                    quemJoga = 1;
                }; break;            
                case 20 :
                if(jogo[2][0] === ''){
                    jogo[2][0] = 'X';
                    quemJoga = 1;
                }; break;            
                case 21 :
                if(jogo[2][1] === ''){
                    jogo[2][1] = 'X';
                    quemJoga = 1;
                }; break;            
                case 22 :
                if(jogo[2][2] === ''){
                    jogo[2][2] = 'X';
                    quemJoga = 1;
                }; break;
        }
    }
    //////////////////////// Daqui pra frente são jogadas do Player 2:
    else if((quemJoga === 1) && (jogoRolando)){
        switch(p){
                case 00 :
                if(jogo[0][0] === ''){
                    jogo[0][0] = 'O';
                    quemJoga = 0;
                }; break;
                case 01 :
                if(jogo[0][1] === ''){
                    jogo[0][1] = 'O';
                    quemJoga = 0;
                }; break;
                case 02 :
                if(jogo[0][2] === ''){
                    jogo[0][2] = 'O';
                    quemJoga = 0;
                }; break;
                case 10 :
                if(jogo[1][0] === ''){
                    jogo[1][0] = 'O';
                    quemJoga = 0;
                }; break;            
                case 11 :
                if(jogo[1][1] === ''){
                    jogo[1][1] = 'O';
                    quemJoga = 0;
                }; break;            
                case 12 :
                if(jogo[1][2] === ''){
                    jogo[1][2] = 'O';
                    quemJoga = 0;
                }; break;            
                case 20 :
                if(jogo[2][0] === ''){
                    jogo[2][0] = 'O';
                    quemJoga = 0;
                }; break;            
                case 21 :
                if(jogo[2][1] === ''){
                    jogo[2][1] = 'O';
                    quemJoga = 0;
                }; break;            
                case 22 :
                if(jogo[2][2] === ''){
                    jogo[2][2] = 'O';
                    quemJoga = 0;
                }; break;
        }
    }   

    atualizaTabuleiro();
    vitoria = verificaVitoria();
    
    if (vitoria != ''){
        if (quemJoga = 0){
           // alert(vitoria + " Venceu!");
           mensagemWinner(vitoria);
            jogoRolando=false;
        } else {
            mensagemWinner(vitoria);
               // alert(vitoria + " Venceu!");
                jogoRolando=false;
            
        }
    }
}
```

```html
        <div class='div-container'>
            <div class="header">
                <p>Turn:</p>
                <p id='turn'> </p>
               
                <select id='gameMode'>
                    <option value="0">Game Mode:</option>
                    <option value="1">Player vs Player</option>
                    <option value="2">Player vs CPU - EASY</option>
                    <option value="2">Player vs CPU - HARD</option>
                </select>
                
                <button onclick="restart()">Restart Game</button>
                <img src="./assets/old-lady-icon-68.png" alt="jogo-da-velha">
            </div>
            <div class="table">
                <div class="cel" id='00' onClick='jogadaComp(00)'></div>
                <div class="cel" id='01' onClick='jogadaComp(01)'></div>
                <div class="cel" id='02' onClick='jogadaComp(02)'></div>

                <div class="cel" id='10' onClick='jogadaComp(10)'></div>
                <div class="cel" id='11' onClick='jogadaComp(11)'></div>
                <div class="cel" id='12' onClick='jogadaComp(12)'></div>

                <div class="cel" id='20' onClick='jogadaComp(20)'></div>
                <div class="cel" id='21' onClick='jogadaComp(21)'></div>
                <div class="cel" id='22' onClick='jogadaComp(22)'></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: cria uma function, associa ao evento "onchange" do select, veja o valor do select e baseado na option executa a function que deseja

Comment: mas dai como eu mudo a funcao que é chamada no Onclick.. me parece que ela esta fixa la e nao tem como mudar

Answer (score 0):

Nesse trecho de código ao selecionar uma opção ele passará por uma função que irá verificar o valor selecionado e direcionar para a função que executará o código da opção.

```js
function opcaoSelecionada(val){
     if(val == 1){
       playerVsPlayer()
     }else if(val == 2) {
       playerVsCpuEasy()
     }else if(val == 3){
       playerVsCpuHard()
     }

  }

  function playerVsPlayer(){
    console.log('Você selecionou a opção Player VS Player');
  }

  function playerVsCpuEasy() {
    console.log('Você selecionou a opção Player VS CPU (EASY)');
  }
  
  function playerVsCpuHard() {
    console.log('Você selecionou a opção Player VS CPU (HARD)');
  }
```

```html
<select id='gameMode' onchange="opcaoSelecionada(this.value)">
      <option value="0">Game Mode:</option>
      <option value="1">Player vs Player</option>
      <option value="2">Player vs CPU - EASY</option>
      <option value="3">Player vs CPU - HARD</option>
</select>
```